# Confusion over using generic repository in .NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, design-patterns

I'm developing services with a micro service architecture using .NET Core 6. I'm trying to follow clean architecture advice and have created 3 layers, `Core` (I put my use cases, repository interfaces, and my dto models), `API` layer, and `infrastructure` (connection with DB and implementation of repository interfaces).

The problem is the number of repositories is increasing, because I'm creating a separate repository for each different job, for example `IStoreCarPricesRepository`, `IStoreCarSparePartRepository`,..... I was thinking, would it not be wiser to have a generic repository and and just create a class to call it and do the jobless say you are getting different messages from different queues and was to store them in the respective tables?

As far as I searched for generic repository is kind of outdated, I would appreciate your comments

Comment: what do you mean by "Genericrepository is kind of outdated" ?

Comment: @CodingMytra meant its not advised,because maybe not very readable,i give you an example,   _ = await this.genericrepository.InsertAsync(carNames).ConfigureAwait(true); compare it to   _ = await this.carRepository.InsertCarNamesAsync(carNames).ConfigureAwait(true)

Comment: readability can be improved with names you used. i didn't get your question here ?

Comment: @CodingMytra considering the problem I explained(having many repositories) is the generic one is the solution or better keep the current way?

Comment: in my personal opinion, you can go for generic repositories as long as you are not doing many customization for different entities.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Generic repository:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace DAL
{
    public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
    {
        internal SchoolContext context;
        internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

        public GenericRepository(SchoolContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "")
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query.ToList();
            }
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetByID(object id)
        {
            return dbSet.Find(id);
        }

        public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
        {
            dbSet.Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(object id)
        {
            TEntity entityToDelete = dbSet.Find(id);
            Delete(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(TEntity entityToDelete)
        {
            if (context.Entry(entityToDelete).State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                dbSet.Attach(entityToDelete);
            }
            dbSet.Remove(entityToDelete);
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            context.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can instantiate and use it for each table:

```
private GenericRepository<Department> departmentRepository;
private GenericRepository<Employee> employeeRepository;
```

Read more about generic repositories [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

Answer (score 0):

Repo doesn't works with jobs and messages.

The main responsibility of repository is a wrapper for common operations (CRUD) or maybe some work with tables for example count, any, some, all.

If you wish to create a microservice architecture, it is useful to check generic repositories in GitHub and create your own library and move the generic-repository here. It should be something like `YourName.Microservice.Core`.

After that, connect it through a nuget-extension to your `Microservice.Core`.

In the future, you need to extend them to avoid a duplication of code in a lot of microservices.